# A camera representation is missing from my scene. How can I see it?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I will be teaching a Blender class in January and I have downloaded the latest version of Blender.  I am going through the **BlenderBasics_4thEdition2011.pdf** that I've chosen to use as a text.  I'm creating a text file that is a record of my progress through that book.  Now I've gotten to the camera setup procedure and I can not see a representation of a camera in my scene, so I expanded the transform menu, exposing an auxiliary panel.  Atop this panel is a Scene Tree diagram that shows all of the elements in the scene.  I found that you could right-click on the Camera listed there and choose the Select option that appears atop the choices.  Then with the Camera selected first, I could hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the Empty.  The text says that both objects will be highlighted - though I can't verify that because I cannot see the camera.  I did press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to add a "Track To Constraint" but the next thing the book says to do is move the camera and I can't see it to move it.

To get around the problem I started a new file and was able to move the camera that came with the standard scene.  Is there a way to show the Camera Icon that I am not aware of?

---

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, Thanks very much!

Comment: Try Alt+H. If you accidentally press the H key with it selected, it will hide the camera in the viewport. Alt+H unhides all elements in the view.

Comment: Try selecting the camera from the outliner as you have done and press numpad [.] (period), this will center the view on the selection.

Comment: The camera might be on a different layer. See [Layers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Layers).

Comment: A link to your ~.Blend file, the one with the unvisualized camera, would be most helpful.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise It seems that your suggestion fixed the problem, If you put that as an answer it will take this question off the “unanswered” list.  Good work!

Comment: @RandyVanNostrand Instead of editing the answer into the question, please click the tick next to the answer. That will mark the answer as "accepted" which awards extra reputation to the answerer, marks the question as solved etc..

Comment: @pinkvertex your link is dead

Answer (score 3):

This is a very common issue for newer Blender users. There are many hotkeys that they are not aware of, and because of that may unwittingly do something not intended. 
This is a prime example of that. You appear to have accidentally pressed <kbd>H</kbd> while your camera was selected. This keystroke is the Blender shortcut to hide objects in the viewport. To make all objects in the scene visible again, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This un-hides all objects in the current viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, and it ***MAY*** be that Cameras added in the Sculpt layout (or others) are not immediately drawn with the usual icon.  Once the user has switched to Layout, err, layout, the flag is properly set somewhere and subsequently the Camera icon is drawn correctly in all layouts.  (2.80)