# What does prevent the camera object to show up in a 3D viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

For Blender 3.1.

With a fresh new project with the default configuration and switching to the `Animation` workspace, two 3D viewports are shown: What is viewed from the local camera (with its passe-partout) and what is viewed from the scene camera:

[image]

<sup>Default Animation workspace</sup>

If the local camera viewport is changed into a scene camera viewport, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, the camera object is invisible (left below), contrary to the other viewport:

[image]

<sup>Camera visibility is different between viewports</sup>

The missing overlays can be recovered using related the `Show Overlays` listbox but where is the setting used to configure the view to not show the camera?

What I checked:

- Camera visibility (eye) is checked in the Outliner list.
- `Show in viewports` in the camera properties is checked and `Viewport Display` is set to `Textured`.
- Camera visibility is checked in `View Object Types` selector for the viewport.
- `Show Gizmo` switch in the viewport has no influence on the camera visibility.

But obviously this is not enough and there another setting hidden somewhere. Someone knows?

---

These questions are related to an object visibility problem, but apparently not applicable:

- [My camera turned invisible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67389/15265) (N panel setting, not present in 3.1)
- [My camera object is invisible in viewport, and tools don't work for it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/159553/15265) (camera type hidden).
- [A camera representation is missing from my scene. How can I see it?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19750/15265) (camera hidden using h).
- [Camera not in Outliner or in 3d view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/124028/15265) (camera deleted).
- [Objects disappearing in viewport but visible in outliner](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51132/15265) (local view and other suggestions not applicable).
- [Objects Not Showing in Other Workspace Viewports, Only Default](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111995/15265) (local view).
- [Objects not appearing in Blender in 3d viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50189/15265) (wrong layer).

And finally a list of 26 possible reasons:

- [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67490/15265) (these applicable to a camera: Object hidden, clipping distance, scene layer, local view, Cycles filter, camera disabled, wrong scene, ray visibility).

Comment: I think that the "viewport camera" is looking at the scene from a position where the camera object is not visible.  If you select all and hit numpad-period to frame everything the camera should show up -- or just select the camera to frame it.

Comment: Ah, yes, Quellenform's answer nailed it.  I'd forgotten that 'extras' were removed from overlays in that window in the workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "Extras" of the *Viewport Overlays* here:

[image]

Comment: Invaluable knowledge. Finally a [27th reason](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67490/15265) to know for an object not showing up.